# Tipo de relacionamento entre as tabelas(Laravel)

Tags: banco-de-dados, laravel, modelo-relacional, entidade-relacionamento

estou implementando meu TCC, sobre fotos e tal..
Mas agora me pegou uma dúvida na hora de criar as tabelas...
Estou usando Laravel ok?

Seguinte, tenho as seguintes tabelas:

```
users - roles - photos - tags
```

funciona da seguinte maneira:
Existem funções de:
1) Fotografo
2) Cliente(que seria o cliente do fotografo)

Ou seja, um fotógrafo terá vários clientes.

Na table photos, eu havia pensado nas colunas:

```
|  photos       |
| id            |
| path          |
| imageable_id  |
| imageable_type|
```

O imageable_type porque  por exemplo, o fotógrafo terá a imagem de perfil dele, o cliente tambem, o fotografo poderá ter imagem da empresa, e quando houve um ensaio fotografico, haverá várias fotos linkando o fotografo ao cliente. Mas nesse caso estaria faltando uma coluna para vincular o fotografo com o cliente?

Para as tags

```
| tags           |
| id             |
| description    |
| taggable_id    |
| taggable_type  |
```

Este eu creio que seja mais fácil porque o type, ou vai ser uma tag para a foto ou vai ser uma tag para um ensaio, somente isso...

Mas em relação a photos mesmo, que tipo de relacionamento é? Polimorphic ManyToMany??

Espero que tenha explicado com êxito, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Eu vejo alguns relacionamentos...

Seguindo a ideia do negócio (me corrija se precisar de adaptação):

```
**Users** (contém Cliente e Fotográfo)
id
nome
cpf 
login
senha
ft_perfil
> outros dados, se necessário
```

*Login e senha, você pode por numa tabela apartada para um controle de quando a pessoa errar senha ou quiser trocar e manter um histórico para não permitir senhas iguais. Ficaria:

```
**acesso**
id_user (fk da Users)
login
senha
nr_tentativas (definir limite de tentativas quando a pessoa errar)
status (bloqueado, ativo, inativo)
```

Como fotográfo possui n clientes:

```
**r_fotografo_cliente**
id_fotografo (fk da users)
id_cliente (fk da users)
dt_associacao (data em que o fotografo foi associado a este cliente)
(ambos FK da user)
```

Como essa combinação de formada, há fotos...

```
**fotos**
id_fotografo (FK da r_fotografo_cliente para não perder a integridade!)
id cliente (FK da r_fotografo_cliente para não perder a integridade!)
path          
imageable_id
imageable_type
```